# How to show source code of an html file rendered in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've include a file in my script via i frame.

```
    <iframe id="iFrame" src="index2.html" frameborder="0"  style="overflow:           hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%"    width="100%"></iframe>
```

Now i want to show the source code of index2.html in this file. How can i do this

Comment: Inscpect (right click) if you are using chrome

Comment: i think first you should open index2.html on new tab by clicking right click of mouse and choose this frame as open in new tab,

Comment: no, i want to show source code to my users and this should be done by programming. not in this way bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the `innerHTML` via Javascript using the following line of code:

```
var sourceCode = document.getElementById('iFrame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

When using jQuery the following line of code should do the trick:

```
var sourceCode = $('#iFrame').contents().find("body").html();
```

Comment: Works perfectly